Restore-GPO -All Doesn't Output or Restore GPOs Bulk Restore
Hey I'm trying to restore GPOs in bulk, I exported the GPOs with the Backup-GPO
Moved them to an office site AD which would be used for disaster recovery.
but when I run the Restore-GPO -All -Path "GPOs Location" nothing happens.
What could be the problem? or is there an other way I can bulk import GPOs
I tried to use the Import-GPO command but I can't find the Backup ID that is requested.
From the GUI I can import a GPO but I would need to create a new GPO first, which would be slow.

Either you should specify a DC name with -server parameter,
OR the DC on which you restore GPO should contact PDC Emulator with necessary ports open.
To find Group Policy port information you may refer the article below;
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj572986(v=ws.11)
You can find PDC Emulator via the command “netdom query fsmo”
“If you do not specify the name by using the Server parameter, the primary domain controller (PDC) emulator is contacted.”
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/restore-gpo?view=windowsserver2022-ps#:~:text=The%20Restore%2DGPO%20cmdlet%20restores,from%20its%20most%20recent%20backup.
